# Adding an extra image gallery into magento add/edit product area

Tags: magento-1.9

I am wanting to add an extra image gallery into Magento so we can upload fabric images for only certain products if possible?

Basically we are wanting to add an extra tab into the add/edit product area which allows you to upload images of fabric options. Would this be possible?

I have tried fabric swatch plugins but these don't show an extra gallery, these show on the selectable option its-self.

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra product attribute which type you gave to choose `image`.
It will display in Product Image area of product in admin.